# If $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous on $X$ then for all $x\in X$ there exists $f_x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n(x)\to f_x $

Tags: functional-analysis, equicontinuity

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $H$ be a countably dense subset of $X$. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of function $f_n:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f_n(x)\to f_x\qquad \forall x\in H
$$
We suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous on $X$.
Can we say that: for all $x\in X$ there exists $f_x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$
f_n(x)\to f_x
$$

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343626/equicontinuous-sequence-of-functions-that-converges-pointwise-in-a-dense-subset

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem can be generalized as follows:

Let $X$ be a metric space and $Y$ a complete metric space. Let $H\subseteq X$
be a dense subset. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f_{n}:X\rightarrow Y$
be a map. If:

(a) the family $\{f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous,
and

(b) for each $x\in H$, $\lim_{n}f_{n}(x)$ exists.

Then for each $x\in X$, $\lim_{n}f_{n}(x)$ exists.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Proof: Let $x\in X$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta>0$
such that $d(f_{n}(x),f_{n}(y))<\varepsilon$ whenever $d(x,y)<\delta$
and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $H$ is dense in $X$, there exists $y_{0}\in H$
such that $d(x,y_{0})<\delta$. Note that $(f_{n}(y_{0}))_{n}$ is a convergent
sequence in $Y$, so there exists $N$ such that $d(f_{m}(y_{0}),f_{n}(y_{0}))<\varepsilon$
whenever $m,n\geq N$.

Now, let $m,n\geq N$ be arbitrary. We have that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & d(f_{m}(x),f_{n}(x))\\
 & \leq & d(f_{m}(x),f_{m}(y_{0}))+d(f_{m}(y_{0}),f_{n}(y_{0}))+d(f_{n}(y_{0}),f_{n}(x))\\
 & < & 3\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $(f_{n}(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence in the complete metric
space $Y$ and hence $\lim_{n}f_{n}(x)$ exists.

Comment: Comments:
1. In the original question, $X$ needs not be a normed space and the completeness is irrelevant.
2. H needs not be countable.
3. However, it is crucial that the codomain ($\mathbb{R}$ in the original question) is a complete metric space.